# How to administrate storage of ClickHouse server in a Cluster when disks get full

Tags: database, sharding, clickhouse

I'm setting up a ClickHouse server in cluster, but one of the things that doesn't appear in the documentation is how to manage very large amount of data, it says that it can handle up to petabytes of data, but you can't store that much data in single server. You usually will have a few teras in each.
So my question is, how can I handle it to store in a node of the cluster, and then when it requires more space, add another, will it handle the distribution to the new server automatically or will I have to play with the weights in the shard distribution.

When you have more than 1 disk in one server, how can it use them all to store the data?

Is there a way to store very old data in the cloud and download it if needed? For example all data older than 2 years can be stored in Amazon S3 as it will be hardly requested and in case it is, it will take a longer time to retreive the data but wouldn't be a problem.

What solution would you find to this? Handling an ever exapanding database to avoid disk space issues in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you use standard configuration for the ClickHouse cluster: several shards consisting of 2-3 replica nodes, and on each of these nodes a ReplicatedMergeTree table containing data for its respective shard. There are also Distributed tables created on one or more nodes that are configured to query the nodes of the cluster ([relevant section in the docs](https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#Distributed)).

When you add a new shard, old data is not moved to it automatically. Recommended approach is indeed to "play with the weights" as you have put it, i.e. increase the weight of the new node until the volume of data is even. But if you want to rebalance the data immediately, you can use the [ALTER TABLE RESHARD](https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#Resharding) command. Read the docs carefully and keep in mind various limitations of this command, e.g. it is not atomic.

> When you have more than 1 disk in one server, how can it use them all to store the data?

Please read the section on configuring RAID in [the administration tips](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/doc/administration/tips.txt).

> Is there a way to store very old data in the cloud and download it if needed? For example all data older than 2 years can be stored in Amazon S3 as it will be hardly requested and in case it is, it will take a longer time to retreive the data but wouldn't be a problem.

MergeTree tables in ClickHouse are partitioned by month. You can use ALTER TABLE DETACH/ATTACH PARTITION commands to manipulate partitions. You can e.g. at the start of each month detach the partition for some older month and back it up to Amazon S3. Or you can setup a cluster of cheaper machines with ample disk space and manually move old partitions there. If your queries always include a filter on date, irrelevant partitions will be skipped automatically, else you can setup two Distributed tables: table_recent and table_all (with the cluster config including the nodes with old partitions).

Answer (score 2):

Version 19.15 introduced multidisk strorage configuration. 20.1 introduces time-based data rearrangements.